# Java ServerSocket/Server works only once

Tags: java, networking, io

so I wanted to setup a very basic chat application in Java. So I wrote a server and a client.

Server:

```
        port = 9694;

        server = new ServerSocket(port);

        client = server.accept();

        optStream = client.getOutputStream();
        optWriter = new PrintWriter(optStream);

        iptStream = client.getInputStream();
        iptReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iptStream));

        while(terminateServer == false){

            String s = null;

            if((s = iptReader.readLine()) != null){

            optWriter.write(s + "\n");
            optWriter.flush();

            }
        }

        optWriter.close();
        iptReader.close();
```

Client:

```
        client = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 9694);

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        optStream = client.getOutputStream();
        optWriter = new PrintWriter(optStream);

        iptStream = client.getInputStream();
        iptReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iptStream));

        while(terminateClient == false){

            this.send(getMessage());

            this.receive();

        }


        optWriter.close();
        iptReader.close();

    }

public void send(String text){

    String s = null;

    s = text;

        optWriter.write(s + "\n");
        optWriter.flush();

}

public void receive(){

    String a = null;

    try {

        while((a=iptReader.readLine()) != null){

            System.out.println(a);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public String getMessage(){

    String s = null;

    s = sc.nextLine();

    return s;


}
```

My plan was to use a while loop so that I could repeatedly send messages. But for some reason it only works once. You type in a piece of text and then the server returns it. You can type in another one but the server wont return it.

Someone got an idea why?

Comment: The overall structure of your code is not clear (which class contains which method or member, which threads are running). Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` returns null at end of stream, which in this case only occurs when the peer disconnects. The `while` loop around the `receive()` call is therefore completely pointless. Once the peer has disconnected, `readLine()` will return false no matter how many times you call it.